# Fetching Rapid API data

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

[Data Screenshot][1]
Hi,
I am trying to fetch information from quote API (Quote, Author), but I am having difficulty to fetch author data.
Could you please help on this?

(especially for below code line

```
  .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quoteauthor").innerHTML=response.originator[1]})
```

)

Below is JS file

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'Key',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'quotes15.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};
function getQuote(){
fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
       .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=response.content})
       .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quoteauthor").innerHTML=response.originator[1]})
    .catch(err => console.error(err));}
```

below is HTML file body section

```
<body>
    <button onclick="getQuote()">Give me a quote!</button>

    


 <div>
   
    <p style="text-align: center" id="quote"></p>;
    <p style="text-align: center" id="quoteauthor"></p>
 </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
[Not displaying author][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD17C.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mejNQ.jpg
```

Comment: hey, welcome to stackoverflow! please elaborate - what kind of "difficulty" are you having? what does the console say? what does the response look like?

Comment: Hi, I uploaded a screenshot "Data Screenshot" with hyperlink, you can check how data looks like :)  I can fetch quote sentence but not quote author info with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get a *"quoteauthor"* because of an error: "**TypeError: response is undefined**".

You can try to debug your code in order to figure out where **fetch** is failing (maybe it's because of catch part), also use **console.log()** it will help you in your investigations.

Let me a little bit rewrite your code snippets if you don't mind.

***HTML part***

```
<body>
<button id="getQuote">Give me a quote!</button>
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center" id="quote"></p>
  <p style="text-align: center" id="quoteAuthor"></p>
 </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

***JavaScript part***

```
const quoteButton = document.getElementById('getQuote');
const quote = document.getElementById('quote');
const quoteAuthor = document.getElementById('quoteAuthor');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key' : 'your_key',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'quotes15.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

quoteButton.addEventListener('click', getQuote);

async function getQuote() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/', options);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Getting error: ${response}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    quote.innerHTML = data.content;
    quoteAuthor.innerHTML = data.originator.name;
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

With this approach you've got a quote and an author

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) It works but I have a few questions.  Actually JS part was directly from rapidAPI page, so I wanted to keep that code for simplicity, is there any reason for using "await, addEventListener"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you tried

```
response.originator[1]
```

response.originator is not an array, is a map, so you should do for the author's name

```
response.originator.name
```

and for the quote itself

```
response.content
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried that too, but still it's not showing author info either with this. it's just showing as 2nd screenshot I uploaded (bottom of the post), below is the code I modified
 .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=response.content})
       .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quoteauthor").innerHTML=response.originator.name})

Comment: maybe the quoteauthor paragraph has a style that hides it. put something like an "-" inside the paragraph to make sure it shows up

Comment: to verify maybe try `console.log(response.originator.name)`

Comment: Hi, console.log(response.originator.name) doesn't show anything, any other recommendation?modified code is this  .then(response => console.log(response.originator.name))   And I put extra texts in quoteauthor paragraphs and it shows that text

Comment: could you show a screenshot of the output of that `console.log(response.originator.name)` ?

Comment: Hi, it's my bad, yes that quoteauthor works https://paste.pics/KCMSC, but i found the problem.    if I try to fetch 2 info (quote, author) at the same time, quoteauthor doesn't work https://paste.pics/KCMT8 . when I disable one of two lines it shows the info correctly. Anyone know how to solve this problem? .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=response.content})
    .then(response=> {document.getElementById("quoteauthor").innerHTML=response.originator.name})